# How to include 'Source Edit' plugin in RTE component in AEM 6.5?

Tags: html, rte, aem-6, aem-touch-ui

I have added the features node with asterix(*) and added misctools#sourceedit in the inline properties of the RTE pluggin node.But still the sourceedit functionality isnt working where I can use some HTML.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to add feature with asterix(*) or sourceedit to misctool plugins(text/rtePlugins/misctools) to enable the source edit functionality.
[image]

and misctools#sourceedit to inline toolbar property